# Why does htmlElement only return content of element when returned in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to dynamically create a tabel containing name and three radio buttons. The output should be:

```
<tr>
   <td>Jane Doe</td>
   <td><label class="radio-inline" id="foo"><input type="radio" name="bar"></label></td>
   <td><label class="radio-inline" id="foo"><input type="radio" name="bar"></label></td>
   <td><label class="radio-inline" id="foo"><input type="radio" name="bar"></label></td>
</tr>
```

in javascript I am using functions to create the TD, containing the label containing the input:

```
function createRadioTdElement(naam, value){
    var radioTdElement = document.createElement('TD');
    var labelElement = createLabelElement(value);
    var radioElement = createRadioElement(naam);
    labelElement.appendChild(radioElement);
    return radioTdElement.appendChild(labelElement);
}

function createLabelElement(value){
    var labelElement = document.createElement('label');
    labelElement.className = 'radio-inline';
    labelElement.id = value;
    return labelElement;
}

function createRadioElement(naam) {
    var inputElement = document.createElement('input');
    inputElement.type = 'radio';
    inputElement.name = naam;
    return inputElement;
}
```

however when I call this function to append it to a TR element:

```
eTR.appendChild(createRadioTdElement(naam, value));
```

the createRadioTdElement only returns:

```
<label class="radio-inline" id="foo"><input type="radio" name="bar"></label>
```

why does it not return it with the "td" tags like:

```
<td><label class="radio-inline" id="foo"><input type="radio" name="bar"></label></td>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild *The returned value is **the appended child***, not the parent.

Comment: `return radioTdElement` after appending label in you function.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand why this has to do with the appendChild? 
if I put all these lines after each other and not split it in functions, it works fine. It loses the "td" tags in the return statement. 
only returning the radioTdElement and seperating it from the appendChild function does not help. It still loses the TD tags.

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry. It did help. I thought I had it like that before and still had the problem, but apparantly not. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The comments answered the question but I figured I would write a working example for completeness.

Kevin mentioned that [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) returns the appended child, not the parent. So you want to return the `<td>` element which I commented below.

Additionally, the `id` attribute should be unique. So I also changed the `id` in my example below.

```js
function createRadioTdElement(naam, value){
    var radioTdElement = document.createElement('TD');
    var labelElement = createLabelElement(value);
    var radioElement = createRadioElement(naam);
    labelElement.appendChild(radioElement);
    radioTdElement.appendChild(labelElement);
    return radioTdElement; // return td element
}

function createLabelElement(value){
    var labelElement = document.createElement('label');
    labelElement.className = 'radio-inline';
    labelElement.id = value;
    return labelElement;
}

function createRadioElement(naam) {
    var inputElement = document.createElement('input');
    inputElement.type = 'radio';
    inputElement.name = naam;
    return inputElement;
}

var td = createRadioTdElement('bar', 'four');
var tr = document.querySelector('tr');
tr.appendChild(td);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>Jane Doe</td>
     <td><label class="radio-inline" id="one"><input type="radio" name="bar"></label></td>
     <td><label class="radio-inline" id="two"><input type="radio" name="bar"></label></td>
     <td><label class="radio-inline" id="three"><input type="radio" name="bar"></label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```